# Present keyboard from right of the view in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I have a view controller with some textfields when user click the textfield i need to present the keyboard from right side of the view ipad portrait screen.its possible to show the keyboard in right side

Comment: Yes, it is possible but you need to make your custom keyboard view and make open it with animation. You can't do it with default keyboard.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh can u have any example

Comment: Please a look https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=keyboard

Comment: @DharmbirSingh So I need to add the custom keyboard view to my right side view?right

Comment: Exactly you need to make a view with your required keys and put it outside of the view and when will you click on text field then make it appear with animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the side of keyboard, you must change the side of the statusBar.
For example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```